# What should I do about this intrusion attempt

Tags: anti-virus, norton-antivirus

I keep receiving this message from Norton Antivirus:

[image: An Intrusion attempt by so and so ip address was blocked, The path was. It has high severity]

What should I do about it?

Should I be worried?

What can I do to stop this?

How it would have harmed my system if I had no anti-virus softwareinstalled in my system at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are exposed to the Internet (not in a LAN behind a router), since port 445 should be closed otherwise.
If not you should check your router portforward rules.
No traffic should be allowed from the internet source to the 445 port since is used to for windows folder sharing.

Comment: How it would have harmed my system if I had no anti-virus softwareinstalled in my system at all

Comment: Well, in fact the firewall blocked it. If you were not using password on your user account a malicious remote user could access your windows shares. Note that with the right privileges (admin) all the drives would be exposed using the administrative share (c$,d$,etc). As I said before, all traffic from the internet should be dropped, if you don't plan to use any server on that computer.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you can ignore it; for a start if it is completely legitimate Norton has blocked it and is claimed that no action is required.

Generally when a firewall says this it is very misleading to the user, all it means is that some network traffic it checked met the pattern of a similar set of network traffic that was known to be bad. So unless you have a service running like VNC Server that someone could use to take control of your system, then its more than likely harmless.

Comment: How it would have harmed my system if I had no anti-virus softwareinstalled in my system at all

Comment: Likely, it wouldn't have - these kinds of things tend to be people trying to brute force passwords on remote services such as Windows Desktop Assistance. The odds of them actually guessing a valid username password combo is slim - presuming there is a service for them to even attack.

Answer (score 0):

You have not to worry much anout it. As many user hss been facing rhis issue and has been discussed on [norton community](http://community.norton.com/t5/Norton-Internet-Security-Norton/Intrusion-attempt-blocked-always/td-p/27511). And also see this [solved thread](http://community.norton.com/t5/Norton-Internet-Security-Norton/An-intrusion-attempt-from-my-computer-blocked/td-p/395580).

Comment: How it would have harmed my system if I had no anti-virus softwareinstalled in my system at all

Comment: Well this is depend on the situations. But if antivirus will not block them may be anyone trying to get or put something harmful on you system. That's why AV programs are there to block them through there firewall and much more protection.

Comment: You should download malwarebyte and [combofix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/) and run a scan to find any infection if there is any.